# How to pass prepared parameter in sql query in talend

Tags: talend

i have an sql query followed by another sql query.
how to pass the output of 1 to the input of 2 .

I have used tdbinput followed by tdbrow. Its now working 
My first query :

```
"SELECT * FROM a WHERE STAGING_STATUS='N' AND ROWNUM <= 1 order by created_date asc"



SECOND QUERY :
"SELECT
A.ID,
A.RECEIVED_DATE,
A.FILE_NAME,
B.ID AS TXN_ID,
B.MERCHANT_NUMBER,
B.TXN_DATE,
B.TXN_TIME,
B.TXN_CURRENCY_CODE,
B.TXN_VALUE,
B.TXN_TYPE,
B.RETAILER_REFERENCE
FROM ABC A ,
BCD B
WHERE A.ID=B.HDR_ID
AND A.ID = ?"
```

Comment: how does subquery come into picture? TdbInput is my first activity which gives me id . I need to pass this id to the second query .How to do that in talend ?

Comment: And why do you want to run a select query in a t*Row component?
If you really want do do that you can do something like:  ='" + row4.colName +"'" instead of = ?"

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it's difficult to understand your question my assumption is that your attempting to pull all of the columns in the second query from the ID's from the first one.

In future please describe your question as clearly as possible.

in order to do this a sub-query or with statement would be useful to convert this from 2 query's to 1 whilst this would more then likely be more a complex and intensive query building the logic in talend to do this would require more effort.

try this:

```
 with first_query as (
 --only select the columns you need... 
 SELECT * 
 FROM a 
 WHERE STAGING_STATUS='N' AND ROWNUM <= 1 order by created_data asc)

SELECT
A.ID,
A.RECEIVED_DATE,
A.FILE_NAME,
B.ID AS TXN_ID,
B.MERCHANT_NUMBER,
B.TXN_DATE,
B.TXN_TIME,
B.TXN_CURRENCY_CODE,
B.TXN_VALUE,
B.TXN_TYPE,
B.RETAILER_REFERENCE
FROM ABC A ,
BCD B
WHERE A.ID=B.HDR_ID
AND A.ID in (select ID from first_query)
```